# Как узнать характеристики фото при загрузке?

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, imagemagick

Как при загрузке изображения получать коэффициент (уровень) размытия контрастности, гистограммы , гаммы. Реально ли сделать это силами `php`, `js`? Какие библиотеки можно использовать?

Comment: у вас уже стоит тег `imagemagick` – это хороший вариант решения.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageproperties.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXIF данные можно прочитать и на клиенте.

https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

https://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader

http://code.flickr.net/2012/06/01/parsing-exif-client-side-using-javascript-2/